# using toString to form a String with Characters

Tags: java, string, character, tostring, cpu-word

using the toString method to add characters into my string I form the word "LAUGHTER". However, the program does not recognize the word = "LAUGHTER" and therefore it did not enter my if loop. Any idea why is it like that?

```
word += Character.toString(cList.get(i));

if(word == "LAUGHTER" )
{
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: YO, I solved it using .equals() instead of ==.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use equals to determine string content is equivalent

word.equals("LAUGHTER")